# Auth::check() worked in controller but not working in view?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I used `Auth::attempt()` to log user:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], true)) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else{
        return 'wrong email or pass';
    }
```

Then I reload browser and call function:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
        return 1;
    }
```

And this `return 1;`

But when I call:

```
@if (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check())
            echo '<label style="width: 20%;color: #ff3f41;margin-left: 10px;">login</label>';
        @else
            echo '<label style="width: 20%;color: #ff3f41;margin-left: 10px;">nothing</label>';

        @endif
```

This print `nothing`.

Any helps. Thanks.

Comment: Is the route that loads this view inside the `web` middleware group?

Comment: Yes, Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { Route::get('login', 'Auth\UserController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\UserController@postlogin');});

Comment: Can you show the controller method that loads the view, as well as the route that points to the controller method?

Comment: You could try to use `\Auth::check()`

Comment: I copy my code in here https://jsfiddle.net/449dekfa/

Comment: It still not working with `\Auth::check() `

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
@if (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check()) ...
```

try to use

```
@if(Auth::Check())
```

This should work. you dont need to call method by its full path in Blade template

Comment: It still print nothing :(.

Comment: what you want to print ??? it only checks that user is Logged-in or not... what you want to print ? 
are you using this in Blade template structure of PHP side ?
if you are using Blade template structure, then you dont need to use echo '....', just write your HTML inside @if/@else

Comment: Yep, I used Blade template, print nothing that mean Auth::Check() return false;

Comment: as per your saying, Auth::check() working in Controller, and not working in Blade template, then try do this.
in you Controller, 
$check = Auth::Check(); and pass that variable into Blade. and in Blade validate like this 

@ if($check == true)

or

@ if($check)

....

@ else

....

@ endif

Comment: I will use this for many times and it must pass variable $check many times :|, some function will redirect this page.

Comment: you can share it as global, instead of calling in each method.

Comment: How to use global variable with multi pages and multi users?

Comment: goto your Controller from which you are extending your all controllers. 

eg: your controller exists in App/Http/Controllers/Controller.php Write this ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;   
    public function __construct() {
         \View::share('breadcrum', 'moduleName');
    }   
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101649/discussion-between-qazi-and-rome-).

Comment: Make sure that there is an active session i.e. you should be logged in before testing. Also see that you save your view with the file extension '.blade.php'. Also extend the right view layouts at '@extends()'. At the end revisit the doc and refresh your mind on views. Courage!!!

Comment: I think user be logged because my controller, line `if (Auth::check())` return `true` ;

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(Auth::Check())
    <label style="width: 20%;color: #ff3f41;margin-left: 10px;">login</label>
@else
    <label style="width: 20%;color: #ff3f41;margin-left: 10px;">nothing</label>
@endif
```

No need namespace in view Because it is defined in Facades, Check it in `config/app.php`

And if you use `brackets` and `echo` in blade You need to wrap them in `<?php tag //code echo 'something' ?>`

Laravel way!
If you need to echo something in View use `{{ }}` or `{!! !!}` The difference `{{ }} escape HTML tags`, `{!! !!} doesn't escape HTML`

Comment: Yep, I remove ` \Illuminate\Support\Facades\` but still not working, it still return `false`;

Comment: How You call this function?  `if (Auth::check()) {
        return 1;
    }` bring More code your Controller or Route

Comment: Ok here `if ($this->auth->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], true)) {
            return redirect('/');
        }` 

Does it Redirects to / page check for browser cookie and etc `dd(Auth::check)` check what returns.

Also check `'config/app.php'` if there is `'aliases' => [ 'Auth' => 'Some/Class'`

Comment: `'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,`
I think user be logged because my controller, line `if (Auth::check())` return `true` ;

Answer (score 0):

goto **App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** in boot(){ } section write this line  `view()->share('key', 'my name is Rome');` 
using this you will be able to globally access "key" variable value in all off your templates

eg: see below

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('key', 'my name is Rome');
    }
}
```